# Does SQL Server has any priority for where clause when use and?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have 2 columns: `Name` and `Price`.

`Price` is a computed column which call a function to calculate the price with some queries.

Now I want to know is there any difference between :

```
select * 
from myTable 
where name like 'j%' and Price > 1000
```

and

```
select * 
from myTable 
where Price > 1000 and name like 'j%'
```

I want to know if I use **name like 'j%' at first** does it have better performance because maybe sql server does not check the computed column at first for all records ?

Comment: Well, when you ran them both and looked at execution time, what did you find?

Comment: @dfundako, I have not many records now, just I want to know it for the future.

Comment: Did you try to run both with the execution plan to compare?

Comment: Absolutely no difference at all. The query engine will evaluate those in whatever order it feels will provide the best option for retrieval. It doesn't matter the order of predicates nor the order of value in each predicate.

Comment: @SepehrEstaki Fill your table with a ton of dummy rows and run it?

Comment: Exactly and to add to what Sean Lange said, the indexes you create on the table will have more effect on performance when you have lots of data.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, if you sure about it, just post it as an answer so I can check your answer as an answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely no difference at all. The query engine will evaluate those in whatever order it feels will provide the best option for retrieval. It doesn't matter the order of predicates nor the order of values in each predicate.